# Is there ever a legitimate reason for an outsider to access wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin

I have a non-wordpress website, and I've noticed I get a lot of 404 errors regarding requests to /wp-admin

My gut instinct is to blacklist the IP address corresponding to any "wp-admin" query, as it is probably someone attempting something uncouth.

But is there any possible legitimate reason for such a query?  Perhaps a search engine trying to determine if I'm running wordpress?

(Note: I understand the paradox of asking a question about a non-wordpress site on a wordpress development site, but my question pertains directly to a wordpress feature so I hope you find it relevant.)

Comment: WordPress advertises itself in meta tags by default so there's no good reason to try crawling URLs to detect WordPress. There are plenty of automated attacks like this e.g. POSTs to /xmlrpc.php too or phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, lots of themes and plugins make use of the `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` file, and some use `wp-admin/admin-post.php`. But beyond that there's little to no reason to access `wp-admin`.

> Perhaps a search engine trying to determine if I'm running wordpress?

Search engines don't care so much if you are or aren't using WordPress, you would be able to tell via the user agent if it was a searchbot. If it is, then this implies you have links to nonexistent files in `wp-admin` that would show up in tools such as google web console, etc.

But if they did care, which they don't, there are far better ways to identify a WordPress than querying `wp-admin`.

**What this is *likely* to be, are automated attacks.** Almost all hacking attempts are automated, they don't even check your site. Exploits are fire and forget. Why make requests to a site to figure out if the exploit will work when you can just run them all? If one of them works that's all it takes.

For this reason, you'll see a lot of login attempts and exploit requests that aren't even for your software. My WordPress sites get Drupal exploits and attempts to login to Joomla URLs, and I ignore them. Iff they ever became an issue I would block them at the Nginx level or lower.

At the end of the day, we cannot know for certain. If you are concerned you might break things, contact the community around your CMS and ask them. For all I know you use a CMS called WonderPage that just happens to have a `wp-admin` folder

Comment: Thank you, I understand that these are [nearly?] always malicious attacks, I was just wondering whether there is any case where it is not a malicious attack, especially for a site that is not based on wordpress at all.

Comment: Other than the 2 files I mentioned I'm unaware. Unless your CMS has a `wp-admin` folder I don't see why.

Comment: Otherwise, if you're afraid of breaking something, you should ask in your CMS' community, they will know the answer for that specific CMS

Comment: I am the specific CMS community, this is a custom-built web application I wrote that serves my specific website.  I just wanted to check if there was any legitimate service somewhere that would query a website for wp-admin, otherwise I'm happy to blacklist anyone who makes such a request.

Comment: If you use `wp-admin` then yes, if you don't, then no, otherwise there's no reason for 3rd party services to be querying `wp-admin` that aren't browsers. There _might_ be, but I've not heard of any. Fundamentally, the question is asking to prove a negative, which isn't possible

Comment: Proof by lack of counterexample is possible-ish (until proven otherwise!)

Comment: Questions need to be phrased in such a way that they can be concretely answered in a factual authoritative manner, but this sounds like it has more in common with recommendations. Remember, this isn't a discussion forum.

Comment: "need to be" lol

Comment: If they aren't they run the risk of being closed. If you'd like to discuss this further though, you should ask about it on the meta stack. Comments are for clarifying questions not discussion of the site itself